# What is a good programming pattern to prevent html mixed in PHP?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am currently developing a website that containts multiple types of users.

Examples of the types:
type a, type b, type c

all types can do different things with different rights.
What I am currently doing; for example in the navigation is:

```
<?php
if($user_type == "a"){
?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">You can see this</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">And this</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">also this</a></li>
</ul>
<?php
}elseif($user_type == "b"){
?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">You can see this</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">also this</a></li>
</ul>
<?php
}elseif($user_type == "c"){
?>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">You can see this</a></li>
  </ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

And that for every element where they have different rights.

This can look better or not?

Does someone have an example of an design/programming pattern that I can use to prevent if else and html mixed with php?

Thanks :)

Comment: PHP is a templating language, so I recommend making use of includes.

Comment: What you show above looks *fairly* okay. As long as the PHP code only checks the conditions, things aren't that bad. Things become troublesome when additional logic is performed in between the HTML pieces

Comment: are you doing MVC at all? if yes then the controller should have the knowledge of what type of user it is and then call appropriate views. If not using MVC then suggest having a fallback option if $user_type is NOT set at all or if the value is different then what you have.

Comment: @cartalot do you have an example (or link to an example) to do this in the MVC pattern?

Comment: basically if you have a user who is an admin, then that admin is going to be able to do things that other users can't do. so you would have an admin "Controller" that calls admin related methods in a "Model" and then the display of html is in the "View" So then the html page or View is not figuring out if the user is qualified or not. The View has no "responsibilities" and is very simple. i suggest net tuts for many free tutorials like here is  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/mvc-for-noobs/

Answer (score 4):

Theres nothing wrong with the way youre doing it. i prefer to use this syntax though

```
<?php if($user_type == "a"): ?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">You can see this</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">And this</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">also this</a></li>
</ul>
<?php elseif($user_type == "b"): ?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">You can see this</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">also this</a></li>
</ul>
<?php elseif($user_type == "c"): ?>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">You can see this</a></li>
  </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

I think it looks nicer in templates

Answer (score -2):

at a higher more abstract level you can use MVC (the Model View Controller pattern), but that is too much work.

A simpler way to not mix PHP and HTML like that, in your case, would be:

```
<?php

$users = array(
  "a" => '
    <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">You can see this</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">And this</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">also this</a></li>
    </ul>
',
"b" => '
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">You can see this</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">also this</a></li>
  </ul>',
"c" => '
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">You can see this</a></li>
  </ul>
'
);

echo $users[$user_type];
?>
```

---

Although what you're doing is not wrong - although messy - you're using PHP as a pre-processor basically here, which is ok. The code above is just a cleaner way of viewing what you wrote.

If you have more complex logic, you can wrap each code block in a function, e.g.:

```
<?php

$blocks = array(
  'a' => function () { echo 'aaaaaaa'; },
  'b' => function () { for ($i=0; $i<5; ++$i) { echo '<div>bbbb</div>'; } },
  'c' => function () { var_dump($_SESSION); }
);

$blocks[$user_type]();

?>
```

Comment: i personally like his solution better than yours. echoing html makes me unhappy.

Comment: also, mvc is almost no extra work.

Comment: yeah, I also used to hate echoing html because of quotes and escaping and all that. Then I found out about `echo <<<HTML 
whatever 
HTML;` which requires no escaping ^.^

Comment: and MVC adds a lot of extra set up required and it's easy to get wrong :)

Comment: I have never seen an array of anonymous functions before, but it is verry helpfull to handle different cases! :)

Comment: mvc requires no extra setup. just put things in different files and include them. simple.

Comment: that's not MVC :), that's #include or require_once(). MVC is model-view-controller. It's based on resources in a datastore (most commonly a database), a controller which instantiates models and retrieves the information and instantiates views and passes the information to them, and lastly the views which are basically templates. MVC is a design pattern not a function call :)

Comment: you're over thinking mvc. mvc is simply separating the different parts.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller